# Feynman Diagram with Different "Legs"

Tags: luatex, tikz-feynman

I was using the `tikz-feynman` package to build a counterterm diagram according to the following code (using lualatex as compiler):

```
\documentclass[border=0.3cm]{standalone}

\RequirePackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{>=stealth}

\definecolor{myDColor}{HTML}{101010}
\definecolor{myLColor}{HTML}{7736d9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[right] (counter) at (0,0){
        \feynmandiagram[horizontal = a to b, layered layout]{
            a -- [boson, myLColor, momentum=\({\color{myDColor}q}\)] c [crossed dot] -- [boson, myLColor, momentum=\({\color{myDColor}q}\)] b
        };
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Such that the output is:

[image]

My question is, how can I make the length of the line (photon) on the left side the same as the length of the line (photon) on the right side, while keeping the `crossed dot` in the middle?

Comment: Can you please extend your code snippet into code, which compiles, when we copy it? This also keeps us from guessing which feynman package you may have been using ... Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO According to the tag and fifth word in the question, it seems the `tikz-feynman` package is used. @Jimeens That said, I can't reproduce your image. Neither the color nor the different lengths.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry

Comment: @Qrrbrbirbel, sure, but ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you kind of overdo it, as:

- `tikz-feynman` already loads `tikz`
- `\feynmandiagram` already uses a `tikzpicture` environment
- putting `\feynmandiagram` inside a `nodes text` results in unbalanced legs (for some reason)

The code below runs for:

- wrongly pdflatex WITH warnings, stating "use LuaLatex !"
- lualatex

**pdflatex - wrong!**:

[image: pdf]

**LuaLatex - correct**:

[image: lua]

```
\documentclass[border=0.3cm]{standalone}

\RequirePackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
%\RequirePackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{>=stealth}

\definecolor{myDColor}{HTML}{101010}
\definecolor{myLColor}{HTML}{7736d9}

\begin{document}

%\begin{tikzpicture}
%    \node[right] (counter) at (0,0){
        \feynmandiagram[horizontal = a to b, layered layout]{
            a -- [boson, myLColor, momentum=\({\color{myDColor}q}\)] c [crossed dot] -- [boson, myLColor, momentum=\({\color{myDColor}q}\)] b
        };
%    };
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just wondering, if you plan to put several feynman diagrams into a matrix layout or similar: why do you need a `\node`?